# Template class specialization for when the two enum values are the same

Tags: c++, templates, enums, specialization

I have a `Test` class which is templated on two enums of the same enum type.
I'm trying to write a specialization for this `Test` class for when the two enum values are the same.

```
enum class Enum
{
    A,
    B
};

template <Enum ENUM_1, Enum ENUM_2>
class Test {};

template <Enum ENUM>
class Test<ENUM, ENUM> {};

int main()
{
    Test<Enum::A> test;
}
```

The above results however in the following error:

```
main.cpp:23:5: error: too few template arguments for class template 'Test'
    Test<Enum::A> test;
    ^
main.cpp:13:7: note: template is declared here
class Test
      ^
1 error generated.
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Would you agree that `Test` requires **exactly two** template parameters?

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a specialization for this `Test` class for when the two enum values are the same."* -- is this a "true" specialization where the implementation is different than the general case, or are you merely trying to provide shortened notation for when the template arguments are the same? (That is, should `Test<Enum::A>` be different than `Test<Enum::A, Enum::A>`? Related: should the two have the same definition but be treated as distinct types?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test` requires exactly two template parameters. Specializing doesn't remove `ENUM_2`. If you want to instantiate `Test` with a single type and use it for `ENUM_2` as well, you can define a default for `ENUM_2`:

```cpp
template <Enum ENUM_1, Enum ENUM_2 = ENUM_1>
class Test {};
```

Answer (score -1):

Laying out the solution from the accepted response in case it helps others:

```
template <Enum ENUM_1, Enum ENUM_2 = ENUM_1>
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "base\n";
    }
};

template <Enum ENUM>
class Test<ENUM, ENUM>
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test<Enum::A, Enum::B> test_AB{};
    Test<Enum::A, Enum::A> test_AA{};
    Test<Enum::A> test_A{};
}
```

prints out

```
base
special
special
```